# Циклы в Python, взаимодейстие с элементами в итерации

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

Не могу никак понять, как можно взаимодействовать с элементами списка внутри цикла `for i in x` если есть схожие элементы как числа. К примеру, небольшая программа, которая принимает на вход числа и выводит сумму соседей справа и слева, которые вычисляются по индексу:

```
num = list(int(i) for i in input().split())
for i in num:
    if len(num) == 1:
        print (num[0])
    else:   
        if i != num[-1]:
            print(num[(num.index(i))-1] + num[(num.index(i))+1], end = " ")
        else:
            print(num[(num.index(i))-1] + num[0], end = " ")
```

Программа ломается при вводе одинаковых чисел, допустим "*20 10 10 **20** 50 50 10 20*", выводится след результат "*40 30 30 **40** 70 70 30 40*", в 3 элементе вывода должно быть число ***60***, однако на выводе ***40***, в ходе итерации 3 элемент воспринимается как 0 и -1 (значения одинаковые) и следовательно выводит неправильный результат.
 **Хотелось бы узнать, возможно ли внутри итерации более точно проходить по элементам, что бы не возникало таких ситуаций, именно в цикле for или аналогичном, если нет, то как возможно?** И если улучшите программу буду признателен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема вот тут у вас:

```
if i != num[-1]:
```

При указанных входных данных, для 3-его элемента (20 - выделен жирным шрифтом в вопросе) эта проверка дает `False`, т.к. i(20) как раз равно num[-1] (тоже 20).

По сути Вам нужен цикл не по элементам, а по индексам элементов, со специальной обработкой 1-ого и последнего элемента.

Например:

```
for i in range(len(num)):
   if i != len(num) - 1:
      print(num[i-1] + num[i+1], end = " ")
   else:
      print(num[i-1] + num[0], end = " ")
```

А вообще, обработку последнего и первого элемента лучше вывести из цикла.

```
print(num[1] + num[-1], end = " ");
for i in range(1, len(num) - 1):
   print(num[i-1] + num[i+1], end = " ")
print(num[-2] + num[0], end = " ")
```

(При условии, что элементов больше 2-ух)

---

Спасибо @andreymal за напоминание, пройти список одновременно получив и индекс и значение можно с помощью функции `enumerate`:

```
for index, item in enumerate(somelist):
   print(index, item)
```

Comment: `num.index` не исправили.

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо, поправил.

Comment: Вы правы, в ходе цикла 4 элемент воспринимается как последний и высчитывается так же, в итоге могу вынести для себя что в ходе итерации по списку проходить надежнее по индексам а не по элементам. Индексы не смогут повторится в отличии от элементов.

Comment: @akaTaniS, Вы не вполне правы в своем выводе. Просто Вы рассматриваете пример со специальной обработкой некоторых *индексов*, поэтому Вам нужен цикл по индексам. В большинстве случаев это не нужно, и правильнее проходить цикл по элементам: `for item in list:`

Comment: Ещё, если нужны одновременно и индекс, и элемент по этому индексу, то для этого есть `enumerate`

Comment: @akaTaniS Более того, в **большинстве** случаев за цикл вида `for index in range(len(list)):` Вас будут **заслуженно** бить по рукам) П.С. Обратите внимание на предыдущий комментарий.

Comment: Данную задачу я решал месяц назад, сейчас решил бы по другому, но хотел до конца разобраться перебором значений в итерации, поскольку не смог найти какого то более менее емкого описания механики взаимодействия и лучшей реализации, очень хочется понимать что делаю и в дальнейшем такие ошибки не допускать ) Если есть какие то ссылки на такие ресурсы,был бы очень признателен.

Comment: @akaTaniS, ни одна книга/сайт не застрахуют вас от ошибок в будущем. В данном случае вам просто нужно понимать, что метод index предназначен просто для поиска первого элемента списка с указанным значением. А в задаче вам просто был нужен классический цикл со счетчиком.